# HTTP referer issue

Tags: python, django, http

I have this view rendering a static page, but I cannot seem to catch the referer of the page.

```py
def landing(request, referer='google'):
    ''' Loads the landing page '''
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'GET':
        referer = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
        return render_to_response('index.html',
            {'WSGI_DIR': settings.WSGI_DIR,'csrf_value': get_token(request),
                'referer':referer},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It keeps popping:

> KeyError at / 'HTTP_REFERER'

I've imported everything needed. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')`.  Not every request will have a `Referer` header, and if one doesn't you will get exactly this exception.  Test if the result of `get()` is not `None` to see if the header was sent.

Answer (score 4):

Make this change to fix the key error:

```
referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '')
```